# How does traveling between Spaces work in "Folding Beijing"?

Tags: space-exploration, folding-beijing

*Folding Beijing* [just won](http://uncannymagazine.com/article/folding-beijing-2/) the 2016 Hugo Award for Best Novelette.

When I read the story, I have trouble visualizing how the three "Spaces" are physically located relative to each other, so the traveling between Spaces is confusing to me.

The main character is able to travel through the Spaces during an event called the "Change". I fail to see how the "Change" facilitates his travel between Spaces.

Can someone clarify how traveling between Spaces works in that story?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Could you give a little more detail on what problem you are having (possibly how or why the way the story explains the travel does not make sense to you).

Comment: Did you read the story?